# Sonarqube rule S4823 "Using command line arguments is security-sensitive" in .NET Core application

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, asp.net-core-webapi

I use Sonarqube to check for code quality in my project.

I receive the error S4823 `Using command line arguments is security-sensitive` which is described here: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4823?search=using%20command

The error is in code which I didn't change - it is auto-generated during project creation:

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

My application is running for some time in production. It is hosted behind IIS as OutOfProcess. I am wondering if I can safely remove args from ConfigureWebHostDefaults?

I do not recall setting additional arguments anywhere but maybe during the process, something (IIS, Kestrel, system, ...) sets some arguments? In that case, should I live with this warning from Sonarqube or do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your code, `args` are used by `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()`

This method creates a HostBuilder with the default configuration. You can check the code on the [Microsoft Github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/96a3bfed4acffbe88403d5f599cee358b880ac5d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Host.cs).

When it's not null, it's used as a provider of data for configuration. Other default providers are environment variables and `appsettings.{Environment}.json` and appsettings.json. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Some of those parameters can be used for Kestrel (port, timeouts, etc) since you are in a web app. From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1) :

> For out-of-process, `CreateDefaultBuilder` calls `UseIISIntegration` to:
>
> - Configure the port and base path the server should listen on when
>     running behind the ASP.NET Core Module.
> - Configure the host to capture
>     startup errors.

If you check the source code on the [official repository](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3ce6c1dc5b022116ec9b13f9158e092323ac1158/src/Servers/IIS/IISIntegration/src/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs), you can see that parameters (host, port, etc) are retrieved like this :

```
var port = hostBuilder.GetSetting(ServerPort) ?? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable($"ASPNETCORE_{ServerPort}");
```

The documentation states `GetSetting` reads the value from the configuration, so it could be from `args` or environment variables as a fallback.

Since I'm not sure if IIS uses command line parameters or environment variables, you could print the values of args and environment variables to check which ones are provided by IIS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wrote a simple code in `CreateHostBuilder`:
    foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            File.AppendAllLines("debuglog.txt", new[] { $"{DateTime.Now} {arg}" });
        }

and run it under IIS. It seems no arguments were passed, at least in `OutOfProcess` model.